# Error : convert rows to columns in cassandra using pivot

Tags: cassandra, pivot, cql3

I am supposed to write a SQL Query in cassandra to show few rows as columns. The table looks like this with `tag_type_id` values ranging from 1,2,3,..42.

```
+--------+-----------+-------------------+-------+
|asset_id|tag_type_id|           datetime|  value|
+--------+-----------+-------------------+-------+
|       1|         1|2017-07-28 11:25:...|1202.65|
|       1|         1|2017-07-28 11:24:...|1212.17|
|       1|         1|2017-07-28 11:23:...|1214.51|
|       1|         1|2017-07-28 11:21:...|1210.79|
|       1|         1|2017-07-28 11:20:...|1207.01|
|       1|         1|2017-07-28 11:19:...|1208.17|
|       1|         1|2017-07-28 11:18:...| 1205.7|
|       1|         1|2017-07-28 11:16:...|1206.11|
|       1|         1|2017-07-28 11:13:...|1208.53|
|       1|         1|2017-07-28 11:11:...|1207.82|
|       1|         1|2017-07-28 11:10:...|1205.05|
|       1|         1|2017-07-28 11:09:...|1205.56|
|       1|         1|2017-07-28 11:08:...|1204.55|
|       1|         1|2017-07-28 11:06:...|  92.17|
|       1|         1|2017-07-28 11:05:...|1213.93|
|       1|         1|2017-07-28 11:00:...|1205.13|
|       1|         1|2017-07-28 10:59:...|1204.42|
|       1|         1|2017-07-28 10:54:...|1209.42|
|       1|         1|2017-07-28 10:52:...| 1209.6|
|       1|         1|2017-07-28 10:50:...|1213.63|
+--------+----------+--------------------+-------+
```

I need to see the `tag_type_id` of values 39 and 40 as column rather than seeing as a row in same table. I want it like this

```
asset_id tag_type_id    datetime     value tag_type_id    datetime      value 
1            39       2017-07-28 11:25   90   40      2017-07-28 11:25   0.3
1            39       2017-07-28 11:24   91   40      2017-07-28 11:24   0.9
1            39       2017-07-28 11:23   90   40      2017-07-28 11:23   0.024
1            39       2017-07-28 11:22   89   40      2017-07-28 11:22   0.9
1            39       2017-07-28 11:21   91   40      2017-07-28 11:21   0.25
```

I tried to do it using pivot like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server?rq=1) But it throws error:

```
select *
from
(
select tag_type_id, datetime, value
from energydata.demodata where asset_id = 1
) src
pivot
(
sum(value)
for tag_type_id in ([39],[40])
) piv;
```

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 3:0 no viable
>   alternative at input '(' (select *from[(]...)
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 3:0 no viable
>   alternative at input '(' (select *from[(]...)

what should i do to view table like above?

Thank you.

Comment: try self-join the according datetime

Comment: are you using sql-server or cassandra?

Comment: I am using cassandra . I am writing these queries in SQL console in cassandra

Comment: cassandra does not support SQL.. it uses CQL... and in Cassandra all this complex subquries,joins,etc are not available

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.tag_type_id, t1.datetime, t1.value,
       t2.tag_type_id, t2.datetime, t2.value
from table t1
join table t2 on t1.tag_type = 39 and t2.tag_type = 40 and 
                 t1.datetime = t2.datetime
```

Comment: hi i have everything in the same table. Not different table

Comment: sure, I use self-join, everything is in the same table called "table"

Comment: @RadimBača Cassandra does not support joins... and now since sql-server tag is removed this answer does not help